# FluentNHibernate Unidirectional One-To-Many Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes. One is Order:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

The other one is Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

They are fluently mapped like this:

```
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        Table("Orders");
        Id(x => x.Id, "Id");
        HasMany(x => x.Products)
            .KeyColumn("OrderId")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Table("Products");
        Id(x => x.Id, "Id");
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

The database does NOT have a not-null constraint on the OrderId column of the Products table.
Problem is: both the order and the products are being persisted, however the products are being persisted with a null value on the OrderId column.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as strange as it seems, we solved this issue here by re-working our Session management, using it to create an ITransaction in a using statement. Odd, but solved. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

instead of HasMany just use Reference

```
Reference(x => x.Products).Cascade.All();
```

Inverse on HasMany is an NHibernate term, and it means that the other end of the relationship is responsible for saving.

Comment: But it's not a References situation, because References maps the other side of an entity when mapping a bi-directional one-to-many.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
HasMany(x => x.Products)
        .KeyColumn("OrderId")
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.All();
```

Which(Inverse()) states that OrderId is on the Products table